Prove $\frac{a}{bc + 1} + \frac{b}{ca + 1} + \frac{c}{ab + 1} + \frac{27}{10}abc ≤ 1$ for $a, b, c ≥ 0$ with sum $1$.
Question:
Let $a, b, c ≥ 0$ and $a + b + c = 1$. Prove that: $$\frac{a}{bc + 1} + \frac{b}{ca + 1} + \frac{c}{ab + 1} + \frac{27}{10}abc ≤ 1$$
So far:
The above inequality is the same as proving that:
$$\dfrac{1}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{1}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{1}{ca + 1} + \dfrac{27abc}{10} ≤ 1 + \dfrac{a + b}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{b + c}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{c + a}{ca + 1}$$
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{9abc}{10}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{9abc}{10}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{ca + 1} + \dfrac{9abc}{10}\right)$$ $$ ≤ \left(\dfrac{a + b}{ab + 1} + c\right) + \left(\dfrac{b + c}{bc + 1} + a\right) + \left(\dfrac{c + a}{ca + 1} + b\right)$$
So I tried comparing each corresponding part  between the LHS and RHS, for example:
$$\dfrac{1}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{9abc}{10} ≤ \dfrac{a + b}{ab + 1} + c \Longrightarrow abc(1 - 9ab) ≥ 0$$
However, this wasn't true for all $a, b, c$, so I reached a dead-end. I initially attempted via CS inequality, but that was no good either.

Sooo... I'm answering my own question because I think I've constructed a solution to the problem after spending quite some time on it. I think it'd be best to leave this question open in case someone in the future needs help with the same.
By the AM ≥ HM inequality:
$$\dfrac{\frac{1}{ab + 1} + \frac{1}{bc + 1} + \frac{1}{ca + 1}}{3} ≥ \dfrac{3}{ab + 1 + bc + 1 + ca + 1}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{1}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{1}{ca + 1} ≥ \dfrac{9}{ab + bc + ca + 3}\tag{1}$$
Using the algebraic identity:
$$(a + b + c)^2 \equiv a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)$$
we get that:
$$ab + bc + ca = \dfrac{1 - \left(a^2 + b^2 + c^2\right)}{2}$$
$$\dfrac{9}{ab + bc + ca + 3} = \dfrac{18}{7 - \left(a^2 + b^2 + c^2\right)}\tag{2}$$
Next, apply the QM ≥ AM inequality.
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{3}} ≥ \dfrac{a + b + c}{3} = \dfrac{1}{3}$$
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 ≥ \dfrac{1}{3}$$
$$7 - \left(a^2 + b^2 + c^2\right) ≤ \dfrac{20}{3}$$
$$\dfrac{18}{7 - \left(a^2 + b^2 + c^2\right)} ≥ \dfrac{27}{10}\tag{3}$$
Hence, plugging $(3)$ into $(2)$, and then $(2)$ into $(1)$ gives:
$$\dfrac{1}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{1}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{1}{ca + 1} ≥ \dfrac{27}{10}\tag{4}$$
From here, it’s gonna be some rearrangement and manipulation using $a + b + c = 1$. Continuing further with $(4)$, multiply both sides by $abc$.
$$\dfrac{abc}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{abc}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{abc}{ca + 1} ≥ \dfrac{27}{10}abc$$
$$\dfrac{a(bc + 1) - a}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{b(ca + 1) - b}{ca + 1} + \dfrac{c(ab + 1) - c}{ab + 1} ≥ \dfrac{27}{10}abc$$
$$a + b + c - \left(\dfrac{a}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{b}{ca + 1} + \dfrac{c}{ab + 1}\right) ≥ \dfrac{27}{10}abc$$
$$\boxed{\therefore\dfrac{a}{bc + 1} + \dfrac{b}{ca + 1} + \dfrac{c}{ab + 1} + \dfrac{27}{10}abc ≤ 1}$$
Equality holds if and only if (by equality condition of AM ≥ HM inequality):
$$\underbrace{(a, b, c)}_\text{unordered} = \left(\dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{3}\right), (a, b, 0), (1, 0, 0)$$
Q.E.D. $\blacksquare$
With that being said, I would definitely love alternatives for the problem. Here are some alternatives suggested by others using Titu's Lemma and Jensen's Inequality:
Solution using Titu's Lemma
Solution using Jensen's Inequality

A possible useful step: since $ a,b,c\geq 0$ and $a+b+c =1$, one also has that $\ a,b,c \leq 1$, so we can write the fractions as convergent geometric series:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\quad \frac{a}{bc + 1} + \frac{b}{ca + 1} + \frac{c}{ab + 1} + \frac{27}{10}abc\\
&= a\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-bc)^k \right) + b\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-ca)^k \right) + c\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-ab)^k \right)+\frac{27}{10}abc\\
&= (a + b+c) - 3\, abc +\frac{27}{10}abc - abc\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-bc)^{k-1} + (-ca)^{k-1} +(-ab)^{k-1}\right) \\
&= 1 - abc\left( \frac{3}{10} - \frac{bc}{bc + 1} - \frac{ca}{ca + 1} - \frac{ab}{ab + 1} \right)\\
&= 1 - abc\left( \frac{3}{10} - abc\left(\frac{1}{a(bc + 1)} + \frac{1}{b(ca + 1)} + \frac{1}{c(ab + 1)}\right) \right)
\end{aligned}$$

True, though I think I've constructed my solution after a lot of thinking
